# search paramters between 2 snippets

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have 2 snippets, which are in 2 ui:composition :

(1)

```
     <p:panel id="pSearchParamas" >
     <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="field">
            <h:outputText id="lNickname" value="Nickname : " />
            <p:inputText id="itNickname" value="#{usersSearchController.nickname}" immediate="true"></p:inputText>
       </div>
        <div class="field">
            <h:outputText id="lDisplayName" value="Display Name :" />
            <p:inputText id="itDisplay" value="#{usersSearchController.displayname}" immediate="true"></p:inputText>
       </div>
        <div class="field">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <h:outputText id="lAge" value="Age :" />
                <br/>between<br/>
                <p:inputMask id="itAgeMin" value="#{usersSearchController.minAge}" mask="99" immediate="true" ></p:inputMask>
                <p:slider for="itAgeMin" step="5" maxValue="100" minValue="15" />
                <br/> and <br/>
                <p:inputMask id="itAgeMax" value="#{usersSearchController.maxAge}" mask="99" immediate="true" ></p:inputMask>
                <p:slider for="itAgeMax" step="5" maxValue="100" minValue="15" />
            </h:panelGrid>
       </div>
        <div class="field">
            <h:outputText id="lCountry" value="Country :" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="somCountries" value="#{usersSearchController.countryId}" immediate="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{countriesController.allCountriesItems}" ></f:selectItems>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="AttributesArea">
        <h:outputText id="lAttributesArea" value="Attributes:"  />
    </div>
</p:panel>
        <p:commandLink id="bSearch" value="Search" action="#{usersSearchController.prepareResults}"
                       update="main:searchContentSnippet" process="pSearchParamas" ajax="true" >
        </p:commandLink>
```

(2)

```
     <p:outputPanel id="pResults" >
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{usersSearchController.results.rowCount > 0}">
        <p:dataGrid id="dtResults"
                    value="#{usersSearchController.results}"
                    var="item"
                    rows="10" columns="10" >
            <p:column>
                <p:panel header="#{item.displayName}" style="text-align:center">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.displayName}"></h:outputText>
                        <p:graphicImage rendered="#{imagestickiesController.image != null}"
                                        value="#{imagestickiesController.image}" width="100" height="100"
                                        binding="#{imagestickiesController.imageforuserid}" >
                            <f:attribute  name="uID" value="#{item.userID}" />
                        </p:graphicImage>
                        <h:outputText id="lAboutMe" value="#{item.aboutMe}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataGrid>
        <br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.pageFirstItem + 1}..#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.pageLastItem + 1}/#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.itemsCount}"/>&nbsp;
            <h:commandLink action="#{usersSearchController.previous}" value="#{bundle.Previous} #{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.pageSize}" rendered="#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.hasPreviousPage}">
                <f:param   name="currentPageNumber" value="#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.page}"/>
                <f:ajax render="pResults"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink>
                &nbsp;
            <h:commandLink action="#{usersSearchController.next}" value="#{bundle.Next} #{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.pageSize}" rendered="#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.hasNextPage}">
                <f:param   name="currentPageNumber" value="#{usersSearchController.paginationHelper.page}"/>
                <f:ajax render="pResults"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink>
                &nbsp;                    
</h:panelGroup>
    <br/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Now, I wish to make a search by using the given search paramters (from snippet 1) and update the values in snippet 2 (p:dataGrid). What happens is that the setters and getters of the search parameters are being called after the execution of the query (that runs in order to populate the dataGrid). 
I'm searching for a solution that will make the parameters raedy for the query (setters and getters in some way must be executed before the query runs - the query runs on usersSearchController.results).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the token and values, you can use "Apache Velocity" to replace the token with the values.

Comment: how can I integrate JSF 2.0 with "Apache Velocity"...?